# Exception for error produced while running arcpy.MakeXYEventLayer_management method

Tags: arcpy, python-3

I am using Python 3.6.8 to make an XY Event layer. I first use the `arcpy.MakeXYEventLayer_management(inputCSV, "Longitude", "Latitude", TempFeatureLayer, WGS84, "")`

where `TempFeatureLayer` is defined earlier as "XYTemp", and WGS84 is the variable holding the GCS_WGS84 coordinate system info.

I pass this and get an error the first time that is pretty extensive but the end says: "

> SystemError:  returned a result with an
>   error set"

I am able to continue running the code successfully inspite of this seeming error. I would like for this to simply not show up as the code will go to someone with little experience and I dont want this to trigger concern.

Interestingly when I run the code again for the next input, this error does not appear again....

Does anyone know of an exception handling i can use to eliminate this?

I am currently running 10.7 desktop and have been working in the jupityer notebooks version that comes with this desktop version.

I have attached the error and the Python code I wrote. the section happens at line 277

```py
workingDir = r'C:\Users\e17864\Desktop\CPSE_Analysis\Datasets\ByYear\Incidents_'+year#Change
workingGDB = os.path.join(workingDir, "CPSE_FinalDatasets.gdb") 

ap.env.overwriteOutput = True
ap.env.workspace = r"C:\Users\e17864\Desktop\CPSE_Analysis\Datasets\CPSE_FinalDatasets.gdb"

WGS84 = "GEOGCS['GCS_WGS_1984',DATUM['D_WGS_1984',SPHEROID['WGS_1984',6378137.0,298.257223563]],\
               PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]];\
               -400 -400 1000000000;-100000 10000;-100000 10000;8.98315284119522E-09;\
               0.001;0.001;IsHighPrecision"
XYEventsTemp = "XYEvents" + year #Change Name
XYEvents = "XY_WGS" + year #Change this name
ProjectedLayer = "IncidentData" + year + "_NAD83" #Initial Dataset projected into NAD83_Harn_NM State Plane

XYEventsFL = ap.MakeXYEventLayer_management(CleanedIncidentsPath, "Longitude", "Latitude",XYEventsTemp, WGS84, "")

#Makes XY Event Layer real- prep to join district and parcel data
ap.CopyFeatures_management(XYEventsFL, XYEvents, "", "0", "0", "0")
```

```
Error:
SystemError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py in f(self, other)
   2089     def f(self, other):
   2090 
-> 2091         other = _align_method_FRAME(self, other, axis=None)
   2092 
   2093         if isinstance(other, ABCDataFrame):

C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py in _align_method_FRAME(left, right, axis)
   1949         return right
   1950 
-> 1951     if isinstance(right, np.ndarray):
   1952 
   1953         if right.ndim == 1:

SystemError: <built-in function isinstance> returned a result with an error set
```

Comment: The one thing you have not shown is the actual input `CleanedIncidentsPath`? What is it, data source, location and full name?